# Is there any ways to implement in oracle sql column default, like today() in excel?

Tags: sql, excel, default-value

Is there any possible way to make the column in sql oracle be like today() function in excel. Which will be show the today's date. I've tried using "SYSDATE" in the default value column but it does not change day by day means it only take the submission date.
[default value column](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5lpmJ.png) I need it changes to the current date.

Comment: Why would you want that?

Comment: Add it to a view.

Comment: I need that column date to calculate aging days up until current date(today)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to *select* the column.  The default value is assigned when a row is inserted.

One method would use a view:

```
create view v_t as
    select t.*, trunc(sysdate) as today
    from t;
```

If you want the value in a particular format, either set the format in Excel or use `to_char()`, such as `to_char(sysdate, 'MM/DD/YYYY')`.

Comment: Thank you this maybe helpful, but i don't have a privileged to create the view.

Comment: @codelover . . .Then include the column in your `select` statement.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT TO_CHAR
(SYSDATE, 'MM-DD-YYYY HH24:MI:SS') "NOW"
 FROM TableName;
```

Answer (score 0):

I found that i can achieve that, if I : **update tablename
set DATETODAY = TRUNC(SYSDATE)** :
Is that efficient? Can we schedule the column to be update everyday/certain time